# Deep copy props that contains object arrays and string arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**Goal:**

I need to have the props read and writable in the component.

---

**Challenges:**

1. Props are read only. I believe deep coping/cloning will solve this.
2. I cant figure out how to deep copy the props as it contains different variable types, such as string arrays and object arrays.

---

**These are the variables:**

```
var data = [

{ID: 5, First: "first", Middle: null, Last: "last", Job Listing ID: null, …},

{ID: 6, First: "first", Middle: null, Last: "last", Job Listing ID: null, …},

…

] 

var default_refine_toggle_display = [
   "ID",
   "CV",
   "C Letter",
   "NDA",
   "Photo",
   "Address",
   "First",
   "Middle",
   "Last",
   "Email",
   "Job Title",
   "Status",
 ]

 var fake_prop_change_name = {
   applicant_id: "ID",
   recruiter_id: "Recruiter ID",
   cover_letter_id: "C Letter",
   nda_id: "NDA",
   file_photo_id: "Photo",
   resume_cv_id: "CV",
   file_address: "Address",
   first_name: "First",
   middle_name: "Middle",
   last_name: "Last",
   gender: "Sex",
   personal_email: "Email",
   building_number: "Building #",
   street_number: "Street #",
   street_name: "Street Name",
   town_name: "Town Name",
   state: "State",
   country: "Country",
   applicant_status_id: "Status ID",
   status_datetime_change: "Change Datetime",
   why_should_we: "Why Should We",
   job_listings_id: "Job Listing ID",
   name: "Status",
   Job_title_Status: "Job Title",
   personal_email:"Email"
 }
 var column_order = ["applicant_id", "Status","Job_title_Status", 'first_name', "middle_name", "last_name", "personal_email"];
 var make_view_file = ["CV", "C Letter", "NDA","Photo","Address"]
```

**This is how those variables are being passed to the component:**

```
<Component_table
  default_refine_toggle_display={default_refine_toggle_display}
  fake_prop_change_name={fake_prop_change_name}
  column_order={column_order}
  make_view_file={make_view_file}
  data={database_data['Job Applications']}
  />
```

---

**What I've tried**

1. var props_editable = Array.from(props)
2. var props_editable = props

---

**What I'm trying:**

I was thinking to maybe deep clone each prop individually and then store them in a new array. That way I can handle the deep clone of each prop variable type as it needs.

What are your thoughts on this?

---

I am finding dealing with arrays and objects to require a lot of brain power for me and cant seem to figure this out.

Comment: have you tried spread syntax, It clones array as well as objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone an array, you could use ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It could be helpful in cloning arrays and objects.

**Cloning array of objects**

```js
var data = [
  {
    ID: 5,
    First: "first",
    Middle: null,
    Last: "last",
    "Job Listing ID": null,
  },
  {
    ID: 6,
    First: "first",
    Middle: null,
    Last: "last",
    "Job Listing ID": null,
  },
];

const copyData = [...data];
console.log(copyData);
```

**clone an object**

```js
const obj = {
  name: "Praveen",
  address: {
    streetName: "Amphitheatre streer",
    blockNumber: 8,
    Country: "USA",
  },
};

const cloneObj = { ...obj };
console.log(obj);
console.log(cloneObj);
```